# How to find a document by using specific datetime?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

This code runs perfectly:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 15, 13, 24, 1, 962)

for doc in db.wing_model.find({'sampling_time': {'$gte': dt}}):
    print doc
```

But when I try to find a document with specific datetime like below, it returns nothing.

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 15, 13, 24, 1, 962)

for doc in db.wing_model.find({'sampling_time': dt}):
    print doc
```

Here's my document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b4ae88100285b236134e08e"),
    "value" : [
        {
            "MQ3_ALCOHOL" : 0,
            "MQ5_H2" : 0.39,
            "MQ138_PROPANE" : 4.4,
            "MQ135_ALCOHOL" : 1.25
        }
    ],
    "enose_id" : "node1",
    "sampling_time" : ISODate("2018-07-15T13:24:01.962Z")
}
```

Comment: These 2 code samples look the same, can you please check your question?

Comment: The first and second code snippet essentially looks the same, not sure what is not working,

Comment: it depends upon your time format... In your first query you are finding the documents with `$gte` and in second query you are the documents with `$eq` both the things are different... can you post your sample document

Comment: ups. sorry, my bad.

Comment: change dt to datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 15, 13, 24, 1, 962000) it should work

Comment: what is `datetime` here `datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 15, 13, 24, 1, 962)`?